# How to change code from GET to POST and use object

Tags: java, android, spring, amazon-web-services, http

Eventually using an android app to communicated with my aws server and database, I can locally communicate to the database using postman and GET services for this, but now I am trying to change my spring app to POST and use objects which android studio requires so I can load my app to the cloud and run this from android

What lines need to change, I'm completely new to this, and trying to learn as I go along with this one.

The main controller class

```
@RequestMapping(path="/demo") // This means URL's start with /demo (after Application path)
public class MainController {
    @Autowired // This means to get the bean called userRepository
    // Which is auto-generated by Spring, we will use it to handle the data
    private ImageRepository imageRepository;


    @RequestMapping(path = "/add") // Map ONLY GET Requests
    public @ResponseBody String addNewImages (@RequestParam String word
            , @RequestParam String image, @RequestParam String category,
                                              @RequestParam int number, @RequestParam String users_username) {
        // @ResponseBody means the returned String is the response, not a view name
        // @RequestParam means it is a parameter from the GET or POST request

        images i = new images();

        i.setWord(word);
        i.setImage(image.getBytes());
        i.setCategory(category);
        i.setNumber(number);
        i.setUsers_username(users_username);;



        //imageRepository.save(i);
        return "Saved";

    } 

    @PostMapping(path = "/add")
    public String addsubmit(@ModelAttribute images img){
        imageRepository.save(img);
        return "saved";
    }

    @GetMapping(path="/all")
    public @ResponseBody
    Iterable<images> getAllImages() {
        // This returns a JSON or XML with the users
        return imageRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

The images class

```
public images(String word, byte[] image, String category, int number, String users_username) {
    this.word = word;
    this.image = image;
    this.category = category;
    this.number = number;
    this.users_username = users_username;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getWord() {
    return word;
}

public void setWord(String word) {
    this.word = word;
}

public byte[] getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(byte[] image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(int number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public String getUsers_username() {
    return users_username;
}

public void setUsers_username(String users_username) {
    this.users_username = users_username;
}
```

Comment: Any questions ?

Comment: Great ! Now any question ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should simply change the Requestmethod?

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Comment: Is this all that is required to do so? What about changing parameters into an object?

Comment: This annotation changes the REST-Resource to POST. If you want to consume objects instead of strings, you have to do add consumes=Application_JSON_Value (or xml, or whatever you use). If your project contains a parser for eg JSON, you can simply pass an Object to the function.

Answer (score 0):

To change the request type you have to do following:

```
@RequestMapping(path="/demo", method=RequestMethod.POST)
```

If you want to post an object (e.g. as JSON) to the endpoint you send this object as method parameter and annotate it with @RequestBody

```
public @ResponseBody String addNewImages (@RequestBody Object body) {}
```